# How to create barcodes using ReportViewer Local Report VS 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, barcode, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to figure out how to create barcodes using ReportViewer Local Report VS 2008.

I find a component at:
www.neodynamic.com/barcodes/Interleaved_2_of_5_Barcode_asp_net.aspx

It seems there is no other solution native... Is there another alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of barcode you need. For basic barcodes you could just use [free barcode font](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/)

Comment: how add this Font in Report Viewer

Answer (score 1):

I've always implemented barcodes using a font. Barcodes are nothing more than data presented in a different way. Instead of human-readable they are "barcode scanner readable", so to speak.

You'll need to find fonts (Google search - there's lots available for free) that suit the symbology (or symbologies) supported by the scanner being used. Some readers need start and stop characters as well. So, for example, if you had an ID value of `123456` you might put that in a textbox on your report surrounded by start and stop character `*` - `*123456*`, and then apply your barcode font to the textbox.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser! But, how exactly you apply the font into the RDLC report?

Comment: You right click , install the font, then on the label you select that font. hey presto you're done.